# Copying Excel active sheet to the end of the workbook with Progress 4GL

Tags: excel, vba, progress-4gl

I'm trying to copy an Excel active sheet to the end of the workbook with Progress 4GL. This is what I've tried so far.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chExcelApplication   AS COM-HANDLE.    /* com-handle for the application */
DEFINE VARIABLE chWorkbook           AS COM-HANDLE.    /* com-handle for the workbook */
DEFINE VARIABLE iSheetCount          AS INTEGER.       /* variable to track the current sheet count */

CREATE "Excel.Application" chExcelApplication.
chWorkbook = chExcelApplication:Workbooks:Open("C:\tmp\test.xlsx").

iSheetCount = chWorkbook:sheets:COUNT.

chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY:after = chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount).
```

This is the relevant VBA code:

```
Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

A quick return for `iSheetCount` itself already giving the correct number of worksheets. How to phrase the `Copy After` on VBA into Progress 4GL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure guess, I don't use Progress 4GL, but maybe consider the other VBA format/syntax of `Worksheet.Copy` that doesn't name the parameter but implies it from it's position in the command : `sheet.copy <before>,<after>`:

```
Sheets(1).Copy , Sheets(Sheets.Count)     'VBA
```

The direct translation *(based purely on your question's code and not based on any real knowledge on my part - I must stress!)* might therefore be:

```
chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY ,chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount).
```

Failing that.. perhaps something like:

```
chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY(,chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount)).
```

---

**UPDATE:**

OP confirms the following worked:

```
chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY(,chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount)).
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond. But to be honest, I've tried the blind shooting approach, re-arranging the position of the parameters after Copy, but none of them lands. `After` itself isn't an Excel constant.

`chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY:after(chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount)).`
`chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY():after = chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount).`
`chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY(, after(chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount))).`
`chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY(after(chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount))).`

To name a few variants that I've tried.

Comment: No, I definitely wouldn't include the `After` at all. Sorry I can't help more. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, a newbie mistake on my part. Turns out your second suggestion works: 
`chWorkbook:Sheets(1):COPY(,chWorkbook:Sheets(iSheetCount)).` 

I just forgot to save the workbook to make the change permanent.

Comment: Brilliant news. Answer clarified for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

/* On "hWorkbook:sheets:COUNT"'s right，create a new sheet */

hWorksheet = hExcelApplication:sheets:item(hWorkbook:sheets:COUNT).

hWorkbook:Worksheets:add(, hWorkSheet). /* keep the **SPACE** after **,** */

hWorksheet = hExcelApplication:sheets:item(hWorkbook:sheets:COUNT).